# Getting ID from added Reaction Emoji

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am honstly looking for this since 6 hours and couldnt find anything...How to can i grap the id of a emoji when adding it as a Reaction? This is my Code:

```
@commands.command()
async def reaction_on_message(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, message_id, emoji):
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    print(emoji)
    #reaction_id = emoji.emoji.id
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Comment: Are you using custom or default emojis?

Comment: At the moment i am using the default discord emojis

Comment: Default emojis don't have IDs

Comment: ohh ok but how can i check which emoji has been used without compairing it with a Unicode character?

Comment: [This](https://emojis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#emojis.decode) may help

Comment: Yeah this helps alot thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, emojis don't really have ids, from what I am assuming if there is a grinning reaction you want to get back `:grinning:`. For that I would use `discordhelp.getNameFromEmote(emoji)` from the [discordhelp library](https://pypi.org/project/discordhelp/).